# user not allowed to perform grant operations

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I granted connect permissions to an user on a database:

```
$ db2 grant connect on database to user dbuser

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

but when I try to grant select permissions or dbadm it gives me an error saying the user doesn't have grant permissions, but i am using for connect, select and dbam

```
$ db2 grant dbadm on database to user dbuser

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0552N  "TSSADM" does not have the privilege to perform operation "GRANT".  
SQLSTATE=42502
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GRANT (database authorities) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html), your user have to have `SECADM` authority in the database to have an ability to grant `DBADM`. Does your user have such an authority?